# Не работает запрос к web api. Как исправить?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Делаю учебную задачу, у меня есть удаленное хранилище ключей,, само апи это три запроса, гет , пост и делит, для создание api использую, Nancy, Asp.netcore, Kestrel. 
Код. 
Сам сервис.

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication11
{
    public class BaconIpsumMessage
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IBaconIpsumService
    {
        void AddEntry(string key, string value);

        BaconIpsumMessage GetEntry(string key);

        void RemoveEntry(string key);
    }

    public class BaconIpsumService : IBaconIpsumService
    {
        private ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> entries = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
        public ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> StorageEntries
        {
            get => entries;
            private set { }
        }


        public void AddEntry(string key, string value)
        {
            entries.AddOrUpdate(key, value, (thisKey, oldValue) => oldValue != value ? value : oldValue);
        }

        public BaconIpsumMessage GetEntry(string key)
        {
            return entries.TryGetValue(key, out var value) ? new BaconIpsumMessage { Key = key, Value = value } : null;
        }

        public void RemoveEntry(string key)
        {
            entries.TryRemove(key, out var value);
        }

    }

}
```

Nancy

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Nancy;
using Nancy.ModelBinding;

namespace WebApplication11
{
    public class BaconIpsumModule : NancyModule
    {
        private IBaconIpsumService storage;

        public BaconIpsumModule(IBaconIpsumService inject)
        {
            storage = inject;

            Get("/api{key}", args =>
            {
                if (storage.GetEntry(args.key) is BaconIpsumMessage entry)
                    return entry;
                return HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
            });

            Post("/api/{key}", args =>
            {
                BaconIpsumMessage entry = this.Bind<BaconIpsumMessage>();

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entry.Key) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entry.Value))
                {
                    return HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                }

                storage.AddEntry(entry.Key, entry.Value);

                return HttpStatusCode.OK;
            });

            Delete("/api{key}", args =>
            {
                storage.RemoveEntry(args.key);
                return HttpStatusCode.OK;
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Сервер поднимается, и работает,  но при использовании запроса Post, ошибка  Бед реквест. При запросе Get, при запросе пустом возвращает правильный ответ сервера.

Comment: `Get("/api{key}"…` ===> `Get("/api/{key}"…`

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо за ответ, а в чем разница прокомментируйте пожалуйста.

Comment: Разница в слеше в маршруте

Comment: @tym32167 да я изменил и вот такой запрос отправлю Post запрос http://localhost:5000/api/?ghjfg=dfgf и в отладчике я все равно вижу что запрос пришел пустой

Comment: И как ваш запрос коррелирует с маршрутом, что вы прописали? Почему вы думаете, что он вообще должен работать? Вы прописываете один маршрут, а запрос отправляете на какой то другой

Comment: @tym32167 да я только вот погрузился в эту технологию я имею ввиду asp.mvc и все остальное. Подскажите  как запрос правильно сделать или маршрут поправить,

Comment: Вот это `/api/{key}` подразумевает, что ваш запрос будет выглядеть как то так `localhost/api/mykey` где `mykey` - значение параметра `key` из маршрута

Comment: @tym32167 вот я так и думал, но применяя такой запрос http://localhost:5000/api/?ghjfg и результат такого запроса я вижу  "statusCode": 404,
    "message": "The resource you have requested cannot be found.",
    "details": "<pre></pre>"  По логике этот Post запрос должен положить ключ в хранилище

Comment: Нет, не должен. Условно вы можете разделить урл на 2 части (на самом деле не две, но я просто для вас упрощаю) — это сам урл и параметры урла. Их разделяет знак вопроса. Например `сам/урл?параметр1=значение1&параметр2=значение2` то есть вы должны ключ отправлять как часть урла, а вы его как параметр пытаетесь отправить, потому сервер и не понимает что вам надо

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо разобрался, проблема была в том, что у меня все заработало если я убираю из урла знак вопрос, то есть  localhost:5000/api/ghjfg=dfgdg

Comment: Так я про это и говорю, можете и знак равенства убрать и все, что за ним `localhost:5000/api/ghjfg`

Comment: @tym32167 меня смутил Postman, я отправлю туда запрос а он мне везде ошибки показывает.